# saving a findOneAndUpdate entry in mongoose and mongDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose to check if a user input already exists in my database, and if it doesn't I want to create a new record with that user input together a processedInput (done by another function elsewhere). Below is the findOneAndReplace function I have set up to accomplish this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({original: userInput},{original: userInput, processString: outPut} , {new: true, upsert: true}
  );
```

Everything seems to run fine but when I check my mongoDB, my collections are not being updated.

I have tried setting upsert to true and using User.save() with no success. There are no connection issues with the database.

Comment: what do you want exactly and add more code

Comment: It's sorted now, all I needed was for the above piece of code to look up a document and update it or create a new one if it's not found. It wasn't saving the data because I didn't have a callback function  (error,data)={...} as an argumanent.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue: I added a callback function as an argument to the findOneAndReplace.

```
callback=(error,data)=>{if(error){console.log(error}
else {console.log(data)}



  User.findOneAndUpdate({original: userInput},{original: userInput, processString: outPut} , {new: true, upsert: true}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using callback you can usnig asyn/await like this :

```
let result  =  await User.findOneAndUpdate({original: userInput},{original: userInput, processString: outPut} , {new: true, upsert: true})

console.log(result)
```